# Keras training works on binary_crossentropy but not categorcial_crossentropy

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

This question is **NOT** a duplicate of the following questions.

[Moved to Tensorflow 2.0, training now hangs after third step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59061334/moved-to-tensorflow-2-0-training-now-hangs-after-third-step)

[Keras sees my GPU but doesn't use it when training a neural network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58455765/keras-sees-my-gpu-but-doesnt-use-it-when-training-a-neural-network)

---

**Breakdown of what I do and what happens:**

When running a simple CNN below, the following output is given and an error occurs. Note that I have already one-hot encoded labels with `tensorflow.keras.utils.to_categorical` so there should be no errors.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow.keras
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Nadam
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Dense, Flatten

# image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 28, 28
num_classes = 10

# the data, split between train and test sets
(x, y), (x_val, y_val) = mnist.load_data()

# float32 for the model
x = x.astype('float32')
x_val = x_val.astype('float32')

print('x:', x.shape)
print('y:', y.shape)
print('x_val:', x_val.shape)
print('y_val:', y_val.shape)

# reshape into required dimensions
x = x.reshape(x.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
x_val = x_val.reshape(x_val.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)

# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
y = tensorflow.keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes)
y_val = tensorflow.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_val, num_classes)

print('Convert class vectors to binary class matrices: 1 becomes {}'.format(y[1]))
print('y:', y.shape)
print('y_val:', y_val.shape)


input_shape = x[0].shape

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(4, 3, 1, padding='same', input_shape=input_shape, activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=tensorflow.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=Nadam(),
              metrics=['acc'])

history = model.fit(x, y, 
                        validation_data=[x_val, y_val],
                        batch_size=128,
                        epochs=100,
                        verbose=1)
```

**Output:**

Note that the CNN just stops training at 36096/60000 in real time. In other words, it is not stuck at 36096 just because its pasted code.

```
x: (60000, 28, 28)
y: (60000,)
x_val: (10000, 28, 28)
y_val: (10000,)
Convert class vectors to binary class matrices: 1 becomes [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
y: (60000, 10)
y_val: (10000, 10)
Train on 60000 samples, validate on 10000 samples
Epoch 1/10
WARNING:root:Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
60000/60000 [==============================] - 3s 55us/sample - loss: 4.9133 - acc: 0.8514 - val_loss: 1.5114 - val_acc: 0.8999
Epoch 2/10
36096/60000 [=================>............] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.9090 - acc: 0.9264
```

**Error:**

```
2019-12-10 13:13:48.694128: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/redzone_allocator.cc:312] Internal: Invoking ptxas not supported on Windows
Relying on driver to perform ptx compilation. This message will be only logged once.
```

---

**On the other hand**

When I change the loss from `categorical_crossentropy` to `binary_crossentropy`, everything works.

**The change:**

```
model.compile(loss=tensorflow.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy,
              optimizer=Nadam(),
              metrics=['acc'])
```

**New output:**

Note that now the CNN runs smoothly; there is no freezing at a certain sample. There is also no `ptxas` error as before.

```
x: (60000, 28, 28)
y: (60000,)
x_val: (10000, 28, 28)
y_val: (10000,)
Convert class vectors to binary class matrices: 1 becomes [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
y: (60000, 10)
y_val: (10000, 10)
Train on 60000 samples, validate on 10000 samples
Epoch 1/10
WARNING:root:Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
60000/60000 [==============================] - 3s 58us/sample - loss: 0.2263 - acc: 0.9745 - val_loss: 0.0710 - val_acc: 0.9891
Epoch 2/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 2s 29us/sample - loss: 0.0460 - acc: 0.9917 - val_loss: 0.0434 - val_acc: 0.9914
Epoch 3/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 2s 29us/sample - loss: 0.0240 - acc: 0.9943 - val_loss: 0.0370 - val_acc: 0.9918
Epoch 4/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 2s 29us/sample - loss: 0.0158 - acc: 0.9958 - val_loss: 0.0283 - val_acc: 0.9932
Epoch 5/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 2s 29us/sample - loss: 0.0120 - acc: 0.9964 - val_loss: 0.0301 - val_acc: 0.9926
Epoch 6/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 2s 30us/sample - loss: 0.0094 - acc: 0.9971 - val_loss: 0.0301 - val_acc: 0.9931
Epoch 7/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 2s 29us/sample - loss: 0.0084 - acc: 0.9974 - val_loss: 0.0310 - val_acc: 0.9932
Epoch 8/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 2s 29us/sample - loss: 0.0078 - acc: 0.9976 - val_loss: 0.0303 - val_acc: 0.9933
Epoch 9/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 2s 30us/sample - loss: 0.0074 - acc: 0.9977 - val_loss: 0.0312 - val_acc: 0.9928
Epoch 10/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 2s 30us/sample - loss: 0.0069 - acc: 0.9979 - val_loss: 0.0308 - val_acc: 0.9931
​
```

**Questions:**

- Did I do something wrong?
- Is there something wrong with `categorical_crossentropy`?

I have tried re-running multiple times, getting the same results.

**System Information:**

```
tensorflow-gpu 2.0.0
keras-gpu 2.2.4
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.0, V10.0.130
cuDNN 7.4.02
Windows 10
python 3.6.8
```

---

**Update:**

I tried what `saurjog` suggested but problem still persists. Training of CNN still freezes with `categorical_crossentropy` but works fine with `biniary_crossentropy`.

**Versions I tried:**

```
TF 1.12.0/CUDA 9.0/cuDNN 7.3.1.20
TF 1.14/CUDA 10.0/cuDNN 7.4.0.20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/7640) Github issue might be of help, although it is still open. It looks like the issue is not specific to the loss functions in your question. Following are the Keras/cuDNN/TF versions that seem to work according to the Github issue discussion thread:

1. Tensorflow 1.12.0/CUDA 9.0/cuDNN 7.3.1.20
2. Tensorflow 1.14/CUDA 10.0

Comment: thanks for the reply. I actually saw this open issue before crafting this question. I was hoping that there is a solution without involving downgrading TF/CUDA/cuDNN. Anyways, I will give it a try.